# How to select/filter vertices in a graph given some Annotation value?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, annotation

I recently found out that making custom annotations to a vertex in a graph is quite useful. But, how can we filter the vertex list/set, given the properties in the annotations?

Suppose I have some graph with 6 vertex and 6 edges:

```
g = RandomGraph[{6, 6}];
```

Then, I set the property `"Something"` for vertex 1 to the value 4, where the remaining vertices are unchanged:

```
AnnotationValue[{g, 1}, "Something"] = 4;
```

So, how could I select these vertices with "Something" equal to 4 (or some other filter, for instance, selecting vertex with `"Something"` > 3?)

I tried:

```
Select[Table[
  AnnotationValue[{g, v}, "Something"], {v, VertexList[g]}], # >= 1 &]
```

Which gives `{4}`, as I expect (the value of `"Something"` for vertex 1). How could I get the name of the vertex instead of the value of `"Something"`? Alternatively, is there any other efficient method of vertex selection/filtering based on annotations?

Another approach would be to test for the presence of an annotation, given that my annotation is only present in certain vertices. In the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annotation.html), there is a mention of `AnnotationNames` precisely to do this, but the function does not exist, a screenshot here (Version 12.1 Windows 10):

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Filtering: `Select[VertexList[g], AnnotationValue[{g, #}, "Something"] > 3 &]`

Comment: The annotation key is `"Something"`. I do not understand your question about getting the annotation key. BTW it's good to be aware that none of this annotation stuff is new. They simply renamed `Property` functions to `Annotation` functions. As far as I can tell, the functionality and syntax are exactly the same.

Comment: It's also good to be aware that working with edge and vertex properties (now called annotations) is horribly slow in Mathematica, with the exception of a few special ones like `EdgeWeight`. Most operations are literally 2-3 orders of magnitude slower than in other graph packages available in other languages.  The simplified interface I provide in IGraph/M tries to avoid the slowest operations, but when the entire system is of such bad quality, that is not much you can do to fix it.  With IGraph/M you can get the "Something"  property for all vertices using `IGVertexProp["Something"][g]`

Comment: I edited the question, I meant the name of the vertex, not the key/value. The filtering option you gave works well for this case. And yeah, I am realizing that `Annotation` takes some time with large networks, but for my current needs it is convenient. Thanks for the reference for `IGVertexProp`, that was actually something else I was wondering about.

Comment: looks like it is a typo in the linked docs page: `AnnotationNames` should be `AnnotationKeys`.